# google maps v3 formatting multiple lines of content in infoWindow

Tags: google-maps-api-3, newline, infowindow

I am trying to create an infoWindow in google maps v3 which contains multiple lines of content. However the "\n" I am using to insert a newline doesn't seem to work. What is the recommended way to insert a newline?

see code:

```
//set content of infoWindow
window.setContent(inspStates[i].name+ "\n"+"total: "+inspStates[i].totalInsp+ "\n"+ info);
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The easiest thing to do it wrap the content in a `div` or in a `p` and then use `<br />` for line breaks.

So something like

```
//set content of infoWindow
window.setContent("<p>" + inspStates[i].name + "<br />" + 
                  "total: " + inspStates[i].totalInsp + "<br />" + info + 
                  "</p>");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use HTML for the content, and put each line in its own paragraph. Line separation helps with readability, especially if any of the lines is long enough to wrap.

```js
window.setContent(
    "<p>" + inspStates[i].name + "</p>" + 
    "<p>Total: " + inspStates[i].totalInsp + "</p>" +
    "<p>" + info + "</p>");
```